# Binary Search Tree insert causing a stack overflow C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert values into a binary search tree.  I have a class for the leaves of the tree, and a class for the collection itself. Here is the class for the leaves:

```
template <class K, class T>
class BSTLeaf{
public:
    BSTLeaf(const K& k, const T& c);
    K key;
    T data;
    BSTLeaf * left;
    BSTLeaf * right;
    void insert(const K& k, const T& c);
private:
};
```

Here is the insert function for the other class that is working as intended:

```
template <class K,class T>
void BSTKeyedCollection<K,T>::insert(const K& k, const T& c){
    if(root != NULL){
        cout << "trying to insert " << c << endl;
        root->insert(k,c);
    }
    else{
        cout << "ROOT WAS NULL" << endl;
        root = new BSTLeaf<K,T>(k,c);
        cout << "The root node contains " << c << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that is causing the overflow:

```
template <class K, class T>
void BSTLeaf<K,T>::insert(const K& k, const T& c){
    //if the key is less than the node it comes to
    if(k < key){
        if(left == NULL){
            left = new BSTLeaf<K,T>(k,c);
        }
        else
            insert(k,c);
    }
    if(k > key){
        if(right == NULL){
            right = new BSTLeaf<K,T>(k,c);
        }
        else
            insert(k,c);
    }

}
```

Not sure if the constructor would be helpful but here it is:

```
template <class K,class T>
BSTLeaf<K,T>::BSTLeaf(const K& k, const T& c){
    key = k;
    data = c;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
};
```

We are allowed to assume that K will always be a type that < and > will work for so that is not an issue. The function will insert a value at the root, insert one more value, and then overflow.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So stop calling `insert` with the exact same parameters with which it was already called and on the exact same node...

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but why do your leaf pages have pointers?

Comment: @DarkFalcon would putting left = left->left and right = right->right before calling the function again be an efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is coming from the recursive call to `insert`. You should call it on the right or left leaf of the current leaf:

```
template <class K, class T>
void BSTLeaf<K,T>::insert(const K& k, const T& c){
    //if the key is less than the node it comes to
    if(k < key){
        if(left == NULL){
            left = new BSTLeaf<K,T>(k,c);
        }
        else
            left->insert(k,c);
    }
    if(k > key){
        if(right == NULL){
            right = new BSTLeaf<K,T>(k,c);
        }
        else
            right->insert(k,c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the same function on the same instance you are in, causing a stack overflow (cyclical calls to the same function).  I think you meant `left->insert(k,c);` and `right->insert(k,c);`.